# MediaPlayer error when playing MP3 stream

Tags: android, media-player

I'm playing around with code for playing an MP3 stream, the code is as follows;

```
 try
 {
   URL url = new URL("streamURL");
   URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
   con.connect();
   con.getContent();
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setDataSource(con.getURL().toString());
   mp.prepare();
   mp.start();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 }
```

Crude, but I'm only playing around at the minute.  This code works fine in the emulator, but when running on my Galaxy S I find the error "Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info -105", in the log file.

Has anyone come across this before, and is this something specific to the Galaxy ?

Many thanks in advance,

Neil.

Comment: haven't you found a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are trying to play an .pls directly or something similar.

try this out:

**1: the code**

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://vprbbc.streamguys.net:80/vprbbc24.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

**2: the .pls file**

This URL is from BBC just as an example. It was an .pls file that on linux i downloaded with

```
wget http://foo.bar/file.pls
```

and then i opened with vim (use your favorite editor ;) and i've seen the real URLs inside this file. Unfortunately not all of the .pls are plain text like that.

tested with android 1.6 and 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead, and see if this works (untested):

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("streamURL");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.connect();
    con.getContent();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(con.getURL.toString()));
    mp.start();
} catch(Exception e)  { }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response.  Your code produces the same error.  I had to modify your create to; MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(con.getURL.toString())) as it was expecting a context as the first parameter.

Comment: Whoops, yes, I did forget the context parameter. (embarassed). Unfortunately that's the only idea I have at the moment.